# Can anyone tell me the name of this Fairy Tail game?

Tags: game-identification

I only have this image of a game from the anime program Fairy Tail:

[image]

Can anybody help me to find out its name?

Answer (score 4):

According to this [blog](http://andreafanmadeproject.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/fairy-tail-battle-of-magic.html) it is **Fairy Tail: Battle of Magic**.  This blog uses the exact same picture to portray [Natsu Dragion](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Natsu_Dragion) from the Fairy Tail series.

However, the blog appears to use assets from released games to design game ideas.  This may have been sourced from **Fairy Tail Portable Guild** or **Fairy Tail Portable Guild 2**, both released before the posting of the blog.  Both of these games have a similar camera and animation style to that shown in the screenshot.  From various youtube clips I would say that it is more likely that the screenshot came from the first game, but I cannot be certain.

An example below from in game footage:

Comment: Right clicking on the image in the question and searching google for the image shows a ton of results that confirm it's Fairy Tail Battle of Magic.

Comment: @ChaseC - Battle of Magic looks like a mod project or some other fangame project.  I couldn't find the actual game (other than various forums/blogs discussing the project in 2011/2012).  The blog I have linked also discusses mods for other games.